# Twitter open datasets

Tags: data-request, nlp, social-media, network-structure

Where can I get Twitter datasets available for analysis?

I found two:

- <s>[The May 2011 Calufa Twitter Scrape](http://www.archive.org/details/2011-05-calufa-twitter-sql)</s>
- [Cheng-Caverlee-Lee September 2009 - January 2010 Twitter Scrape](http://www.archive.org/details/twitter_cikm_2010)

Comment: Can you specify what kind of data do you want? For instance, number of followers and following? Relationships? Tweets? Retweets? etc

Comment: Yes, please clarify -- I have a long list of Twitter screen names for Apache Developers, but I don't know if you want tweet or names.

Comment: Preferably tweets as they're returned by Twitter's API (all fields). API itself is too restrictive for analysis. But other data would be useful as well.

Comment: You might also find the answer to a similar question helpful in looking for historical information: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/fifa-2014-tweets-dataset-for-academic-project/4015#4015

Answer (score 14):

While you will find some exceptions, sharing archived tweets is against Twitter Developer [Policy](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/policy.html#c-respect-users-control-and-privacy).

> Take all reasonable efforts to do the following, provided that when requested by Twitter, you must promptly take such actions:
>
> - Delete Content that Twitter reports as deleted or expired;
> - etc

If a user deletes their own content, the archive should reflect that deletion (which is a massive effort to continuously check).

For that reason, Twitter data sets are often shared as simply two fields: *user_id* and *tweet_id*. Then to reconstruct the dataset, one would query the API with those two keys. Then Twitter can ensure that if the tweet was deleted after the initial grab, the content won't show up in the second.

---

As an exception...  the banning of [Politwoops](http://politwoops.sunlightfoundation.com/), a service from Sunlight Foundation that archive deleted tweets from politicians. It has since been [reinstated](http://readwrite.com/2016/01/04/twitter-politwoops-ban-reversed/).

> It doesn’t appear that Twitter is changing its terms for developers. Instead, the company has reached an agreement with the Sunlight Foundation and the Open State Foundation, another group involved in versions of Politwoops around the world, to offer the an exception.

---

---

If you run the [live stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/consuming-streaming-data.html), you can collect your own (you'll get more tweets than you can deal with).

**edit:** I can add that if you want to 'search' for all tweets, you can use 'lang:en' as your search parameter. See [here](https://twitter.com/search?q=lang:en). Then you can loop over desired langauges.

Answer (score 7):

scraperwiki lets you search twitter for terms, but also allows twitters search operators. here's a quick search for my handle:
https://scraperwiki.com/dataset/crt52ai/view/fpzct4y
they also offer a get a list of followers feature, so not exactly what you are looking for, but a twitter tool nonetheless

EDIT: some sets i came across:
Twitter Data used for sentiment analysis
http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students/
network Twitter Data
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/higgs-twitter.html
social Twitter data
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Twitter.html

EDIT 2: Three more sets:
Arizona State University Twitter Data Set
http://academictorrents.com/details/2399616d26eeb4ae9ac3d05c7fdd98958299efa9
Twitter 2010-10 Dataset
http://academictorrents.com/details/d8b3a315172c8d804528762f37fa67db14577cdb
Twitter Data - NIPS 2012
http://academictorrents.com/details/046cf7a75db2a530b1505a4ce125fbe0031f4661

Answer (score 7):

[72 hours #gamergate scrape](https://medium.com/message/72-hours-of-gamergate-e00513f7cf5d) provides a link to download the dataset.

Comment: Welcome to OpenData.SX! Your linked dataset looks great, but could you please extend your answer a bit to make it clear what the dataset is about?

Comment: The author of the article has taken down the dataset, but you can still access the 9mb CSV file of Tweet IDs: http://waxy.org/random/misc/gamergate_tweets.csv

Answer (score 5):

Check out these links below, and you can also search "twitter" in data.world for other related data. There's quite a few users who are already aggregating this data and creating analyses and cool visualizations. If you're interested in collaborating, some are seeking additional contributors to help build out these datasets further. Hope this helps!

https://data.world/dash/twitter-transparency-reports

https://data.world/socialmediadata/social-circles-from-twitter

Answer (score 4):

There are a several ways to get access to historical Twitter data. Here are some options:

- I've had great luck using [Topsy](http://topsy.com/) in looking at a wide variety of
  tweets ranging from disease vectors in Africa to sentiment analysis.
  Here's the link for [28K #opendata tweets](http://topsy.com/s?q=%23opendata&type=tweet) for the last 20 days. You can
  expand to "all time", search by language, and look at influencers.
- Use the Twitter API to get the data you can for free. Good [developer resources](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public) are available.
- The most comprehensive historical archive may be via [Gnip](http://gnip.com/sources/twitter/historical/), but unfortunately it is not free and it's unclear what the actual costs are.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dataset of relative word frequency for the top 10,000 words in 890 million Tweets, divided by county: https://sites.google.com/site/wordmapperinfo/

Comment: This gives word frequency lists, not tweets.

Comment: True, but OP didn't specify what kind of Twitter data he or she was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the awesome-twitter-data list

https://github.com/shaypal5/awesome-twitter-data

> A list of Twitter datasets and related resources, released under [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).

Table of Contents, as of `now()`

```
1   Twitter Datasets

    1.1   Tweet datasets
        1.1.1   Tweet ID datasets
    1.2   Tweet datasets (labelled)
    1.3   User datasets
    1.4   Lost Datasets

2   Other Lists
3   Tools

    3.1   Data Collection
    3.2   Analysis

4   Academic Papers

    4.1   Demographics Prediction

5   Articles & blog posts
```

---

**Tweet Datasets**

- [Chirps](https://github.com/vered1986/Chirps/) {[Apache License
  2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)} [9m] -
  News-related tweets. Updated daily. Used in the paper ["Acquiring
  Predicate Paraphrases from News
  Tweets"](http://aclweb.org/anthology/S/S17/S17-1019.pdf) by Vered
  Shwartz, Gabriel Stanovsky and Ido Dagan.
- [Arab Spring Twitter
  Dataset](http://dfreelon.org/2012/02/11/arab-spring-twitter-data-now-available-sort-of/)
  {?} [8m] - Roughly 8 million tweets related to the Arab Spring,
  separated by country. Contain tweet IDs and twitter IDS, but no
  tweet contents.
- [Cheng-Caverlee-Lee](https://archive.org/details/twitter_cikm_2010)
  {?} [5m] - A collection of scraped public twitter updates used in
  coordination with an academic project to study the geolocation data
  related to twittering.
- [3 million Russian troll
  tweets](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/russian-troll-tweets/)
  {?} [3m] - Released by 538.
- [Lerman Twitter 2010
  Dataset](http://academictorrents.com/details/d8b3a315172c8d804528762f37fa67db14577cdb)
  [2.8m] - Contains tweets containing URLs that have been posted on
  Twitter during October 2010. In addition to tweets, links of
  tweeting users were followed, allowing the reconstruction the
  follower graph of active (tweeting) users.
- [Twitter_2010](https://www.isi.edu/~lerman/downloads/twitter/twitter2010.html)
  {?} [2m] - Released by Kristina Lerman at USC.
- [MovieTweetings](https://github.com/sidooms/MovieTweetings)
  {[MIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)} [725k] - A live
  movie rating dataset collected from Twitter.
- [Sanders Analytics Sentiment-labelled
  tweets](https://github.com/zfz/twitter_corpus) {?} [5513]
- [Elon Musk Tweets-Until
  4/6/17](https://data.world/adamhelsinger/elon-musk-tweets-until-4-6-17)
- [2015 New Year's
  Resolutions](https://data.world/crowdflower/2015-new-years-resolutions)
- [Trump Tweets, 5/4/09 -
  12/5/16](https://data.world/lovesdata/trump-tweets-5-4-09-12-5-16)
- [ArchiveTeam JSON Download of Twitter Stream, 2011 -
  ongoing](https://archive.org/search.php?query=twitterstream&sort=-publicdate)