# FIFA 2014 tweets dataset for academic project

Tags: data-request, sports, social-media

I am looking to run a Map Reduce framework and do some analysis on a Twitter dataset for the FIFA 2014 World Cup event. I couldn't find a place to get these datasets for free. Can someone suggest a place to get at least a sample of this dataset for free? The dataset I'm looking for is actual tweets posted by the users, which contain related hashtags like #FIFA,#GER Vs #ARG, #BRZ, #Neymar, etc. for the duration of the entire World Cup.

Comment: Why not download tweets via the API?

Comment: @Thomas Unless you have the tweet id or you search by user, tweets aren't retrievable by API search after one week.

Comment: FYI, it's against the Terms and Service to share the tweet data, but you can share the tweet ids. If you find a list of tweet ids related to your topic, then you can use the API to retrieve these tweets.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @philshem I have tweet id's with me. I went through twitter API [GET statuses/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup) using which I can get the entire JSON object for up to 180 requests in a span of 15 min window. I have a total of 3 million tweet id's now. I am planning to write a script or schedule job which sends requests to twitter API once in every 15 min. Is there any better approach than this? In the mean while I am also looking in to option 1 suggested by Jeanne Holm

Comment: @theja_swarup I think you can comma separate 200 (?) tweet ids in one request. Still requires scheduling and patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting access to historical Twitter data may end up coming with a price.  Here are some options:

1. I've had great luck using [Topsy](http://topsy.com/) in looking at a wide variety of tweets ranging from disease vectors in Africa to sentiment analysis. Here's the link for 86K [#FIFA tweets](http://topsy.com/s?q=%23FIFA&window=m&type=tweet) for the last 30 days.  You can expand to "all time", search by language, and look at influencers.
2. Use the Twitter API to get the data you can for free.  Good [developer resources](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public) are available.
3. The most comprehensive historical archive may be via [Gnip](http://gnip.com/sources/twitter/historical/), but unfortunately it is not free and it's unclear what the actual costs are.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jeanne. The first option looks promising. I will look in to it.

Comment: most links here are dead :(