# Corpus of Iranian surnames

Tags: data-request, names

I'm looking for a dataset of names and surnames. Preferably I would like to have Persian (Iranian) names, either in Latin script or Farsi.

It doesn't matter if it is a dataset or a web site/web page etc.

Comment: Twitter seems to be blocked in Iran ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_Twitter#Iran)) but one option would be to use an social media API to aggregate geolocated posts (tweets), then scrape the names. See [here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5594/1511) for more details.