# Testing my code with NoSQL Telecom data

Tags: data-request, json, telecom

Where can I find data sets that can be used to test NoSQL databases? It's better if its applied towards the telecommunications industry.

I have already tried using tabular data but i feel like it doesn't accurately represent reality.

Comment: Please have a look at another such question [**here**](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5695/23283)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a big dataset, but you can use

**[Telecommunications Towers and Antennas](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/telecommunications-towers-and-antennas)**

> Connecticut General Statutes §16-50dd requires the Connecticut Siting Council to develop, maintain and update on a quarterly basis a Statewide Telecommunications Coverage Database that includes the location, type and height of all telecommunications towers and antennas in the state.

json format details: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/telecommunications-towers-and-antennas/resource/adfc775a-7b39-4cf9-aac6-ee36925e3393

raw json data: https://data.ct.gov/api/views/n7zh-5dbr/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD