# Spanish Sentiment Dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm looking for a Spanish language corpus tagged with sentiment (just positive & negative are needed, though neutral might be helpful.) I could use a Twitter dataset, but I'd prefer to use something like the IMDB corpus (that's in English though) so it reflects longer documents better. Is there anything out there that's relevant to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Example) Spanish Language Corpora:

- [ESCOW14](http://corporafromtheweb.org/escow14/#more-76)
- [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/es)
- Any of the wiki projects starting with "es" - https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html
  For example - https://dumps.wikimedia.org/eswiki/20150805/
- http://www.corpusdelespanol.org/
- Twitter API public stream with `lang:es` as stream filter - [details](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1548/1511)

---

[Affective Word list for Spanish](http://neuro.imm.dtu.dk/wiki/The_Spanish_adaptation_of_ANEW_(affective_norms_for_English_words))

> The Spanish adaptation of ANEW (Affective Norms for English Words) is an adaption of the ANEW affective word list for the Spanish language.
>   The wordlist is downloadable from:

```
http://link.springer.com/content/esm/art:10.3758/BF03193031/file/MediaObjects/Redondo-BRM-2007.zip
```

Comment: I might just end up using MTurk to get tags, but do you know if you can get tagged documents as well? Thanks