# Spanish POS (part of speech) tagged dataset

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, corpora, dictionary

Where can I get a spanish POS tagged dataset with universal tags free to download?

Comment: Probably googling "WordNet in Spanish" will help you...

Comment: they are not tagged with universal tags

Comment: relevant, or duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5766/1511 (if duplicate, please flag)

Comment: There seem to be very few options that are both free and can be downloaded. If you don't need to download it, there are a lot more options. Some of these online corpora have powerful interfaces so you don't need to download the dataset.