# Historical Twitter Data

Tags: programming, social-media, python

I'm trying to get historical twitter data starting from 2010 with specific keywords related to S&P500 companies. I will probably end up using their tickers as keywords once I finalize my list of specific companies.

I'm unable to go back more than a week. Has anyone found a way to get around this? I need to be able to have code available for my research paper/presentation. I've tried TwitterSearch and Tweepy packages.

This is the code using TwitterSearch:

```
import datetime
from TwitterSearch import TwitterSearch, TwitterSearchOrder, TwitterSearchException

#the start and end of our twitter data
mindate = datetime.date(2010, 01, 01)

maxdate = datetime.date(2016, 01, 01)


try:

    tso = TwitterSearchOrder() # create a TwitterSearchOrder object

    tso.set_keywords(['sp500', 's&p500']) # let's define all words we would like to have a look for
    tso.set_language('en') # English tweets only
    tso.set_include_entities(False) # entities...
    tso.set_until(datetime.date(2016, 01, 01))  #this doesn't work...

    # it's about time to create a TwitterSearch object with our secret tokens
    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = 'REMOVED',
        consumer_secret = 'REMOVED',
        access_token = 'REMOVED',
        access_token_secret = 'ALSO REMOVED'
     )

     # this is where the fun actually starts :)
    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        print( '\n@%s tweeted: %s' % \
             ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text']) )

except TwitterSearchException as e: 
    print(e)
```

I also need to be able to print the date of the tweet, how many likes/retweets it had, and possibly the number of followers the user has. Lastly, I need to be able to save all the data in a csv file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't find it, but I thought this had come up before ... I think there was a company or two who were archiving twitter and selling access to the historical stuff.

Comment: I think I found it : http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4056/263

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the search index for searching tweets only goes back 7 days. [Link to the documentation here, it can be found under 'until'.](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweet)

You might be able to collect tweets from individual users' timelines, if you have an idea about what users are using those terms in their tweets. You can then use [the User Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) part of the REST API to get up to 3200 tweets from each user to see if they have tweeted those terms before?

It's a bit of an indirect method, and you can't tune the API request to only get tweets with your search terms, but it's a potential workaround.

The R equivalent is to use the twitteR package, which comes with methods like `getFollowers()` which gets a list of followers that follow a particular Twitter account. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent in something like Tweepy.