# Tweets organized by regional location and period of time?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, social-media

Where can I find large data-sets of tweets from people in a certain region (say an entire state or city in the US), during a certain period (say last 6 months, or from June 1st 2015 to June 1st 2016)?

So, for example, a large data-set of tweets from people in Illinois in the last 6 months? Is this possible? Is location something Twitter makes public? Or am I looking at geolocated tweets only?

Comment: have you seen the resource here http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1545/1511 ?

Comment: well if you were running the old twitter build that ran on ruby on rails and you had the geocoder gem you'd just run `request.location.coordinates`. don't mean to be a dick, but that's what you'd do