# Source of multilingual chat/online/contemporary corpus data?

Tags: data-request, nlp, language

I need to develop autocorrection and prediction for mobile keyboard app that will work for some 8-10 most common Latin languages + Russian (English, German, Spanish, Portugues, French, ...). For start, I need NLP corpus for each of those languages.

Ideally all corpora should be from same source and match at least some of these criteria:

1. Written language, typos removed.
2. Large enough: at least 10 million words, the more the better
3. Texts typed in online chats, emails, forms, apps... Or similar. Should include language typically used in those situations.

I have no need for syntax or other tagging, raw texts (optionally tokenized) are just fine. I can pay reasonable price.

Any help or even a pointer into resource is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would also help: If there is no such resource known, perhaps there is a way how to create it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case, and because you may need more languages, I'd suggest the Twitter API:

- [Filter-Realtime](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters) has a filter parameter on `language`.

> This parameter may be used on all streaming endpoints, unless explicitly noted.
>
> Setting this parameter to a comma-separated list of [BCP 47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) language identifiers corresponding to any of the languages listed on Twitter’s [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) page will only return Tweets that have been detected as being written in the specified languages. For example, connecting with language=en will only stream Tweets detected to be in the English language.

- [Sample Stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/sample-realtime/api-reference/get-statuses-sample) endpoint

> Returns a small random sample of all public statuses.

---

Benefits to Twitter API:

- Many libraries to easily connect (multiple python, R, etc)
- Structured JSON
- Language field  `{"lang": "en",}` based on automatic detection (which is sometimes not correct, so maybe put a minimum character filter on the tweets).
- May include geolocation or other interesting metadata.

*(In the past, there have been better twitter streams, but they've reduced access via the API.)*

---

And if the API is not enough data, or too slow, you can find archives of tweets (or just their IDs for API lookup.)

See [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1545/1511) for a start.

Comment: This is an interesting option - type of texts typed on Twitter is probably quite similar to what is typed generally on mobile... But it will definitelly contain typos so point 1 is not matched which is a problem. I can see ways how to mitigate that issue (combining this source with typo-checked dictionaries) but that also decreases value of the data...