# Categorized social media posts dataset

Tags: data-request, social-media

I'm looking for a dataset of categorized posts from social media (preferably twitter) the posts shall be labeled with something like: sport, politics, economy, art, etc.

Comment: quite mature Twitter dataset thread is here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1545/1511

Comment: @philshem but non mentioned what I'm looking for, all datasets are geography based, and information about the twitter user.